# Treat N/A as zero within an IF formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

Please can someone help me fix this formula?

```
=-IF(D11="Cash",D9,D14*12)
```

The issue I have is that when 'cash' is selected in D11, cell D14 shows N/A - is there a way to make excel treat N/A as a zero when 'cash' is selected.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is error value then can use `IFERROR()` function like-

```
=-IF(D11="Cash",D9,IFERROR(D14,0)*12)
```

If it is text value then can try-

```
=-IF(D11="Cash",D9,IF(D14="N/A",0,D14)*12)
```

Comment: Instead of the general `IFERROR()`, the specific `IFNA()` can also be used.

Comment: Thank you to you both but it still isn't working. Using `=-IF(D11="Cash",D9,IFERROR(D14,0)*12)` or `=-IF(D11="Cash",D9,IFNA(D14,0)*12)` I get the #VALUE error and using `=-IF(D11="Cash",D9,IF(D14="N/A",0,D14)*12)` the cell shows 0.00 even when cash is selected in D11 and there is a value in D9?

Comment: I've fixed it, there was a space after the cash on the lookup list - and both the IFERROR(), and the IFNA() work perfectly, thank you so much.